# JXBrowser control over dialog website not responding

Tags: jxbrowser

Hey im having issues with a website in the jxbrowser. it seems like it is running into a timeout or whatever and then in the jxbrowser there is a dialog showing up "website not responding" and i can click on "reload" or "leave".

Can I in any way access this dialog and overwrite it? For instance everytime i would get this dont ask but go to the homepage instead? 
I'm having trouble finding this if it is even possible.

Comment: In case it's a JavaScript dialog you can overwrite it as described in this article: [JavaScript Dialogs](https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/solution/articles/9000013061-javascript-dialogs). Do you have an example of the web site that causes JxBrowser to show this dialog?

Comment: I don't think its a JavaScript Dialog. It pop ups when a website is not responding. Look at this Fiddle: https://fiddle.jshell.net/2cLg9722/#&togetherjs=fOpueJPH0h If you uncomment the infiniti loop the website will not respond anymore. After a while there will be a popup that will say the tab is not responding. This is browser based...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. JXBrowser has a RenderAdapter where a function exists onRenderUnresponsive wich can be overridden. Look at this: https://jxbrowser.support.teamdev.com/support/solutions/articles/9000091687-detecting-unresponsive-web-page

In my case I simply want to reload the website:

```
Browser browser = new Browser();
browser.addRenderListener(new RenderAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void onRenderUnresponsive(RenderEvent event) {
        browser.reloadIgnoringCache(false);
    }
});
```